# Missing StripOffsets field when creating a new gtiff

Tags: python, rasterio

My code that has been working flawlessly (as far as I can tell) now, after some Python and Spyder updates produces error message:

CPLE_AppDefinedError: vaesto1960.tif: MissingRequired:TIFF directory is missing required "StripOffsets" field

when trying to write a new geotiff file. The context is as follows:

```
import rasterio

# first read raster data from a netcdf file:

with rasterio.open('data/total_pop_05dgr.nc') as pop:
    vaesto = pop.read()
    profile = pop.profile
    pop.close()  
    
vaesto1960 = vaesto[4]

# want to write one of the rasters as gtiff, so prepare the profile:

profile.update(nodata = 0,
       driver = 'GTiff',
       tiled = False,
       height = vaesto1960.shape[0],
       width = vaesto1960.shape[1],
       count = 1,
       ) 

# Open a new tif file for writing, and write (also tried writing one band with write_band):

with rasterio.open("vaesto1960.tif", 'w', **profile) as out:
    out.write(vaesto1960,1)    
    out.close
```

The full traceback is here:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\jalavam1\git_local\YYT-C2005-2021\untitled0.py", line 25, in 
with rasterio.open("vaesto1960.tif", 'w', **profile) as out:

File "C:\Users\jalavam1.conda\envs\Mika\lib\site-packages\rasterio\env.py", line 435, in wrapper
return f(*args, **kwds)

File "C:\Users\jalavam1.conda\envs\Mika\lib\site-packages\rasterio_*init*_.py", line 230, in open
s = writer(path, mode, driver=driver,

File "rasterio_io.pyx", line 1122, in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.**init**

File "rasterio_io.pyx", line 70, in rasterio._io._delete_dataset_if_exists

File "rasterio_shim.pyx", line 78, in rasterio._shim.open_dataset

File "rasterio_err.pyx", line 215, in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_pointer

CPLE_AppDefinedError: vaesto1960.tif: MissingRequired:TIFF directory is missing required "StripOffsets" field

Setting the StripOffsets (or any other tags for that matter) hasn't been advised in the rasterio documentation. The code should be pretty much a copy of the example there.

Thanks, Mika

Comment: did you resolve this? I'm in the same boat

Comment: I Solved this error message by changing the output file name. 
I had an existing copy of the file where I had tried (and failed) to save the tiff previously. 
I assume the error was caused when trying to overwrite an existing file...